# Outlook 2010 VBA code to copy only certain appointments from a shared calendar to another persons calendar that i have access to

Tags: vba, calendar, outlook

I am at the copy and edit stage of using VBA and have searched and searched for a code which gets me close but I am used to using VBA for excel not for outlook.

I have a shared calendar which many people add to (internally), once this is complete at the end of the day the appointments relevant to certain external people are added to their calendars, at the moment this is done by manually copying the appointments to the external peoples calendars.

It there a way to write some code which will do this automatically?

All calendars are on outlook and shared via exchange.

Any help is appreciated.

Jon

Answer (score 0):

The Namespace class provides the [GetSharedDefaultFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869575(v=office.15).aspx) method which returns a Folder object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. So, you can access a shared calendar and copy/move items. To get the job done you need to use the [Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867845(v=office.15).aspx) and [Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862723(v=office.15).aspx) methods in the following way, a raw sketch:

```
 Set myCopiedItem = myItem.Copy  
 myCopiedItem.Move myNewFolder
```

Finally, you may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx) article in MSDN helpful.